# couldn't create a lua module in C++ (can't include local header)

Tags: c++, include, include-path

I'm using vs code and g++ to compile c++, however I can't include `lua.h`, `lauxlib.h`, `lualib.h` etc.

this is the terminal (using vscode terminal):

```
C:\MingW\bin> .\g++ C:\Users\leand\Desktop\VSCODE\cpp\template.cpp -o C:\Users\leand\Desktop\VSCODE\cpp\build.exe -I C:\Users\leand\Desktop\VSCODE\cpp\    
C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6kM8pM.o:template.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `lua_tonumberx'
C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6kM8pM.o:template.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `lua_tonumberx'
C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6kM8pM.o:template.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `lua_pushnumber'
C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6kM8pM.o:template.cpp:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `luaL_checkversion_'
C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6kM8pM.o:template.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `lua_createtable'
C:\Users\leand\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6kM8pM.o:template.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `luaL_setfuncs'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[this is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF7zs.jpg) (C:\Users\leand\Desktop\VSCODE\cpp)

this is my code

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "luaconf.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lua.h"

int soma(lua_State *L) {
    double nl = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    double n2 = lua_tonumber(L, 2);
    double resultado = nl + n2;
    lua_pushnumber(L, resultado); /* Empurra para o stack do Lua o valor resultado return 1; /* Informa quantas variáveis estão sendo retornadas para o Lua */
    return 1; // quantas variaveis retornam para o Lua
}

int luaopen_template(lua_State *L){ /* lua_State *L é um tipo de ponteiro específico para a API do Lua */
    luaL_Reg funcoes[] = { /* Recurso para listar funções C que devem ser levadas para o Lua */
        {"soma", soma},
        {NULL, NULL} /* Indicador que a lista acabou */
    };
    luaL_newlib(L, funcoes); /* Define uma nova biblioteca Lua com as funções passadas por Lual_Reg */
    return 1;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Seems like you could include them. Do you also have the actual lua library file?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You know that lua.h is not lua? It's just the header file for lua

Comment: I have the lua source code but it isn't linked with anything on c++, the only thing I took was lua.h etc

Comment: Okay well you actually need to have Lua in your program in order for your program to have Lua. A header file isn't the actual thing. You can either add the source code into your program, or add the library file into your program (which is source code already compiled)

Comment: I'm not embeding lua to my c++ app, i'm actually making a lua module in c++, is it the same process?

Comment: No, slightly different. Does the compiler/linker know it's making a DLL?

Comment: I don't know, what  should I do to do it?